# Can the server crash while testing with the sqlmap tool?

Tags: sql-injection, mysql, sqlmap

When I was pentesting a cpanel web app I've got some passwords but while reading the tables the server went offline.

I can exclude that my ip wasn't blocked because I tried to access the server through VPN and got the same results "server offline".

I could still ping the web app by url and by ip.

The backend is MySQL.

Question: Did the server crash or did it blocked my browser by identifying through a cookie?

EDIT 1
after checking the site with isup.me it seems to be down what caused it?

Comment: Can you ask the site operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firewalls don't block you by cookie. (But to double-check, you can always try incognito mode). Most likely you got IP banned by the WAF. Since VPN is using a different protocol and has nothing to do with your webserver, it should be working.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure check it with different IP like from your Mobile, try to restart your ADSL router, try to ping it from online service, try something like: http://isup.me/ ...etc.

All options are open if SQLMap caused the crash or you open a lot of connections to the server then it crashes...To be certain you should read the **logs of the server**.